# C++23: Is it valid to modify the elements of a `zip_view`?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, std-ranges, c++23

I am trying to figure out under which circumstances a modifying access to an element of a C++23 range (resp. view) is allowed by the standard.

For example, consider this rather elegant version of sorting two vectors in parallel by the values in one of the vectors:

```cpp
std::vector<size_t> keys{…};
std::vector<Foobar> values{…};

auto zip = std::ranges::views::zip(keys, values);
std::ranges::sort(zip, [](const auto & lhs, const auto & rhs) {
    return std::get<0>(lhs) < std::get<0>(rhs);
});
```

This seems to work with the three major compilers resp. library implementations ([see Godbolt here](https://godbolt.org/z/Ka1v5behM)). However, that does of course not mean that it's allowed by the standard.

It is clear that there must be views which do *not* allow modifying their elements. Take for example the `std::transform_view` - what would it even mean to modify one of its elements?

I'm not sure how the standards specifies which views may have their elements modified and which may not. There is the concept `std::ranges::output_range`, which in my eyes is the best candidate. However, `std::zip_view` does not model `output_range`, if I read [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/zip_view) correctly.

So, is my nice vector-sorting thingy above forbidden by the standard and I'm just lucky that the compilers/library implementations still allow it?

Comment: Standard views are [completely](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O8HndvYNvQ4) [broken](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qv29fo9sUjY).

Comment: This is perfectly valid.

Comment: @康桓瑋 Thanks for the encouragement - however I was trying to understand what the standard has to say about this. Can you provide a pointer to where the standard allows (or disallows, or makes any statement about…) modifying the elements of a view?

Comment: The view is just a range with semantic requirements for time complexity, and there are no other additional restrictions. This has nothing to do with whether it can be modified.

Comment: Side note: `std::views` is a shortcut for `std::ranges::views`.

Comment: Another note: I prefer the projected version of algorithms: `std::ranges(zip, std::ranges::less, [](auto& x){return std::get<0>(x);});`

Comment: @Evg I don't say this often, but I would actively recommend against watching either of those talks.

Comment: @Barry Why is that? I'd love to hear some reasoned criticism of these talks. To me, arguments expressed there are strong enough for them not to be just ignored. Problems are never resolved that way.

Comment: @Evg I've written a bunch about it in other contexts (e.g. [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/zq2xdi/are_there_likely_to_be_any_changes_to_views_to/j0x0pc6/?context=3)), but basically: the arguments expressed are actually very weak and the talks themselves are basically anti-informative. They are hyper-focused on very narrow, very weird examples that make little sense on their face and they do little to inform people on how to use the library. If you want good talks on Ranges, check out Tristan Brindle's.

Comment: @Barry Very interesting Reddit discussions, thank you for the link!

Answer (score 4):

A view is just a movable range with more semantic requirements regarding [time complexity](https://eel.is/c++draft/range.view#2), this has no bearing on whether it can be modified, and view can even own the data thanks to [P2415](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2415r2.html).

The difference between the view
and range is mostly semantic, which is why the view needs to inherit `view_iterface` / `view_base` to imply to the compiler that it satisfies these semantics.

> It is clear that there must be views which do not allow modifying
> their elements. Take for example the `std::transform_view` - what would
> it even mean to modify one of its elements?

`views::transform` can still transform the original range into an output range, for example:

```
std::vector v{1, 2, 3, 4};
auto r = v | views::transform(std::identity{});
r[0] = 42;    // v becomes [42, 2, 3, 4]
auto i = views::iota(0u, v.size()) 
       | views::transform([&](auto i) -> auto& { return v[i]; });
i[1] = -42;   // v becomes [42, -42, 3, 4]
```

> However, `std::zip_view` does not model `output_range`, if I read
> cppreference correctly.

`zip_view` can be an output range. For your example, its iterator actually models `std::output_iterator<std::tuple<int, Foobar>>`.

It is worth noting that the standard does have a view to ensure that the original range data is not modified, namely [`as_const_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/as_const_view).

Answer (score 4):

In general, it is always valid to modify the elements of any particular view - except in very particular cases (see below). You've gotten a couple answers already, but let me just note this one:

> Take for example the `std::transform_view` - what would it even mean to modify one of its elements?

Consider something like:

```cpp
struct Point { int x; int y; };

// let's say points is some mutable range of Point
for (int& x : points | views::transform(&Point::x)) {
    ++x;
}
```

That's perfectly valid. We're increasing the `x` coordinate by one in each `Point`. There's nothing about `transform`'s requirements that this violates - `transform` requires *only* that the callable be "equality-preserving". This means that `f(elem)` gives the same value every time you call it on a given value. So something like `[](Point){ return rand(); }` would violate the semantic requirements, but `[](Point& p) -> int& { return p.x; }` is totally fine, as is mutating the resulting `p.x`.

Put differently, if this kind of mutation were bad, then that would basically mean that any mutation were bad. And we're definitely allowed to do something like `++*it;` in a loop.

---

The only case where you are not allowed to (or should at least take care) when mutating elements is for `views::filter`. This is, fundamentally, a very peculiar adapter - because the combination of laziness, multipass, and mutation could lead to very strange behavior. This is because in the `transform` example above, we're mutating `p.x` but we're not changing *whether* `p` is in the range at all. But with `views::filter` (and only `views::filter`), a mutation could actually remove an element! See [mutation through a filter](https://brevzin.github.io/c++/2023/04/25/mutating-filter/) for more info, but the gist of it is that even mutating through a `filter` is only bad if (a) your mutations move elements out of the range (if all of your mutations are predicate-preserving then there can't be any issues) and (b) you're making multiple passes through the range (either explicitly, like actually writing two `for` loops, or implicitly, like using algorithms that themselves make multiple passes).

---

Outside of `filter`, mutation is fair game. Indeed, one of the biggest benefits of the C++ iterator model is precisely that you can actually write this:

```cpp
std::ranges::sort(std::views::zip(keys, values));
```

And making that work, especially in such a way as to reject attempts that are nonsensical, was why we had to make [these `tuple` changes](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2214r2.html#a-tuple-that-is-writable).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I think I get the point - if the object "behind" the view-element is modifyable, you can also modify it through the view.

However, I feel like a real C++ newb here: I can't parse the `&Point::x` in your `views::transform(&Point::x)`. … What kind of expression is that? Sorry for the dumb question. I think that `views::transform(…)` should take something callable, right? `&Point::x` looks like an address-of-member - thingy… but certainly not like a value? Or a callable? Again, sorry, I'm probably just a bit slow today.

Comment: @LukasBarth It is a pointer to data members, which is *also* a callable that can be invoked through the specific class object. `transform_view` invokes callable through `std::invoke`, which can handle pointers to data members/member functions.

Comment: @LukasBarth `&Point::x` is a pointer-to-member data. They're not directly callable using the `f(x)` syntax, but they are `invocable` using `std::invoke`. Most of the standard library uses this enhanced `invocable` concept. So you can construct a `std::function<int(Point)>` from `&Point::x`, for instance. Same for `std::thread`, `std::bind`, etc. Anything that takes a callable can take a pointer to member.

Answer (score 1):

[[range.zip.iterator]](https://eel.is/c++draft/range.zip.iterator) defines

> ```
>    using value_type = tuple<range_value_t<maybe-const<Const, Views>>...>;
> ```

The *maybe-const* tag indicates that `const` is only added for the const-iterators of the view (but any existing `const` from the underlying view will be retained).

Since both `keys` and `values` are modifiable when the zip view is constructed, it's safe to write new values through these iterators as written in the question code.

As you identify, writing to the iterators of a transform view isn't possible when the transform returns an rvalue; these iterators still can't be written (and should be a compile-time error) when proxied via a zip view.